# Mostrar somente o anuncio de quem anunciou

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estou criando uma página de classificados, tenho o login e o registro prontos
E quando o usuário loga leva a página de publicar anuncio!

Quando a pessoa publica o anúncio estou exibindo esse anúncio ao lado com um botão de delete e editar.

Meu problema é o seguinte, que estou retornando todos os anúncios e só quero mostrar os anúncios da pessoa que esta logada!
Ou seja que a pessoa faz o anúncio, e esse anúncio retorne a ela mas somente seu anúncio e nenhuma pessoa mais possa ver esse anúncio! E ela possa editar e deletar, mas essa parte eu vou fazer, só quero que me dê a solução de retorna o anúncio do usuário que o fez.

Acho que vocês sabem como funciona o painel de um usuário de um sistema de classificados.
Cada usuário deve ver somente a postagens que ele fez!

da forma que tenho só estou conseguindo retornar todos os anúncios da tabela e todos estão vendo independente de quem esta logado. E não seria a forma mais correta.

Código da página publicar anúncio! Eu tenho ela nessa situação até agora!

```
    if(empty($_SESSION['active'])){
        header('location: index.php');
    }else{

    if(!empty($_POST)){

        if(empty($_POST['titulo']) || empty($_POST['descricao']) || empty($_POST['valor'])){
            echo "<script>alert('Llene todos los campos');</script>";
        }else{


            include_once "config.php";






            $nom = $_REQUEST['txtnom'];
            $foto = $_FILES['foto']['name'];
            $ruta = $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];
            $destino = "images/".$foto;
            copy($ruta,$destino);

            $id_usuario = $_SESSION['id'];
            $titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
            $descricao = $_POST['descricao'];
            $valor = $_POST['valor'];  
            $telefone = $_SESSION['telefone'];


            $result_anuncios = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO anuncios(id_usuario, nome_foto, foto, titulo, descricao, valor, telefone,hora) VALUES('$id_usuario', '$nom', '$destino', '$titulo', ' $descricao', '$valor','$telefone', now())");

            if($result_anuncios){
                echo "<script>alert('sucesso');</script>";
            }else{
                echo "<script>alert('Erro:');</script>";
            }


        }
   }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/publicarAnuncio.css">
    <title>Anunciar</title>
</head>


<body>
<header>
    <div class="container" >
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8" style="margin-top:12px;">
                <h1>ListoPo</h1>
                <span class="user">Bem vindo <?php echo $_SESSION['nome']; ?></span>
            </div>  
            <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top:2%; text-align:left;">
                <div class="btnInicio" >
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><a style="color:white;" href="sair.php">Sair</a></button>
                </div>    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </header>


    <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="anuncio">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Publicar anuncio</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>


      <div class="container">
      <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="exampleInputtitulo1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="id_usuario">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="titulo" style="margin-top:2%;">Titulo</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputtitulo1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="titulo">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="descricao" style="margin-top:2%;">Descrição</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputdescricao1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="descricao">
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="descricao" style="margin-top:2%;">Nome anuncio</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputdescricao1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="txtnom">
            <input type="file" style="padding-bottom:8%;" class="form-control" id="exampleInputdescricao1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="foto">

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="valor" style="margin-top:2%;">$ Valor</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputdescricao1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="valor">
            </div>        
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-bottom:2%;">Publicar</button>
            </form></div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>





<div class="container" style="margin-top:8%; ">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4"><h3>Publica seu anuncio</h3>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#anuncio" style="margin-top:8%;">Publicar anuncio</button>
</div>





    <div class="col-8">
            <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 600px; text-align:center; border:none; margin-top:-10%; margin-left:25%;">
            <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <?php
                    require "config.php";

                    $sql = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM anuncios");
                    while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){


                        echo '<img style="margin-top:5%;" src ="'.$res["foto"].'" width="195px" heigth="100px">';

                        echo "<div class='titulo' style='text-align:center; margin-top:-1%; '><h3> " . $res['titulo']. "</h3></div>";

                        echo "<div style='text-align:center;  margin-top:-1%;' ><p>" .$res['descricao']. "</p></div>";

                        echo "<div style='text-align:center;  margin-top:-8%;' ><p>  $" .$res['valor']. "</p></div>";

                        echo "<div style='text-align:center; ' ><p>" .$res['hora']. "</p></div>";

                        echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>Editar</button>";
                        echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>Deletar</button>";
                    }


                ?>
            </div>         
             </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Por favor, limite o código a parte específica do problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, o que você está fazendo nesta parte do código

```
$sql = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM anuncios");
```

Você está listando todos os anúncios de todos os usuarios, neste caso você precisa passar o 
ID do usuario logado e trazer apenas os anúncios dele, ou seja, está consulta precisa ser algo assim `$sql = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM anuncios where`user_id`= 123 ");`

Comment: Irmão tu me ajudou muito! Muito obrigado!

Comment: quando precisar, e só postar, vou sempre tentar ajudar!

Comment: Irmão esse projeto que eu estava tentando fazer, queria sua opinião de como ficou! De um programador mais experiente que eu! Posso te mandar meu projeto pra que você possa dar sua opinião ??

Comment: @WorldChannel, eu não sei se isso e possivel aqui, mais tem uma opção de chate aqui, talvez voce possa usar e falar comigo quanto eu estiver online

Comment: Vou tentar! Obrigado..